# Line Integral of a Field

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

I have solved the attached problem. I wish to find out if my approach to the problem is correct?

[image]

Comment: The '$F$ can be written as' is not correct because that's $F\cdot \mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: @ Botond: yes, you are correct. I realised that after i have posted the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not multiply the $\frac{128}{7}$ by $2$, but I think everything else is good.

But I would do it this way:
The $\vec{F}$ is: $\vec{F}(\vec{r})=[x^2-y^2, xy]^T$.
Let's use $t$ for the parametrization, so $\vec{r}=[t, t^3]^T$.
Now rewrite $\vec{F}$: $\vec{F}(\vec{r})=[t^2-t^6, t^4]^T$.
Now rewrite $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}$: $\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t} \mathrm{d}t=[1, 3t^2]^T\mathrm{d}t$
So our integral is:
$$\int_C \vec{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_0^2\vec{F}\cdot\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t} \mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int_0^2 t^2-t^6+3t^6\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int_0^2 t^2+2t^6\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\frac{824}{21}$$